# Debugger vscode siempre da ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, vscode, depuración

como estan? Soy novato en python y estoy usando VSCode como IDE. Tratando de ejercitarme con Merge Sort, quise instalar una muy simple libreria desde PyPI llamada sorting. La instalo correctamente, la importo, la uso en mi codigo y el debugger siempre me da un error del tipo `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sorting'`. Probe con crear un launch.json y configurarlo pero no tuve suerte. Tambien intente crear entornos virtuales con pipenv, instalar la libreria e importarla y tampoco. Si ejecuto mi script desde el interprete de python el programa funciona sin problemas, pero me interesaria poder usar el debugger. PyLint tampoco reconoce la libreria importada.

Aqui el codigo. Muchas gracias

```
import sorting
import random

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tamano = int(input('de que tamano queres que sea la lista?'))
    lista = [random.randint(0, 100) for i in range(tamano)]

    resultado = sorting.merge(lista)
    print(resultado)
```

Comment: No veo ninguna referencia en Internet a un módulo Python llamado `sorting`. ¿De dónde apareció esa referencia?

Comment: Lo he encontrado @CandidMoe https://pypi.org/project/sorting/

Answer (score 0):

Esto puede suceder por dos casos.

1. **Estás usando un entorno que no es el que tiene `sorting` instalado**, en tal caso tienes que cambiar de entorno al que lo tiene instalado con `conda activate <nombre_entorno>`. O también seleccionar el interprete en VSCode con `ctrl + shift + p` y buscando `Select Interpreter` y seleccionando el que quieras usar
2. **En la configuración de VSCode no se encuentran los paths al interprete de Python que estás usando**, y por tanto utiliza alguno que no tiene instalado dicha librería.

Para Solucionar el problema del punto dos, debes de irte dentro de VSCode a `settings` y una vez allí, en el JSON cambiar esta linea:

```
"python.pythonPath":"/el_path/del_interprete_de_python/que_quieras/python3.X"
```

Y también agregar el mismo path a esta lista:

```
"python.autoComplete.extraPaths": ["./path_cualquiera/que_sea/python3.6",
                                   "./path_actual/de_la_libreŕia/sorting/python3.7"]
```

Una vez hecho todo esto, guarda los cambios y reinicia VSCode.